# How to get corresponding property of min value from an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I apologise if it is duplicated. I have a collection like this:

```
{
  game_name:"ABC",
  ...,
  prices:[
    {area: 'US', price_usd: 10},
    {area: 'AU', price_usd: 11},
    ...
  ]
},
...
```

I can get:

```
{game_name:"ABC", min_price:"10"}
...
```

by:

```
db.games.aggregate({
    $project:{
      "game_name":1,
      "min_price":{
        $min:"$prices.price_usd"
      }
    }
})
```

However, the query result what I want is:

```
{game_name:"ABC", min_price:"10", min_area: "US"}
...
```

Anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.games.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "game_name": 1,
    "min_price": {
      "$min": "$prices.price_usd"
    },
    "min_area": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$prices.area",
        { "$indexOfArray": ["$prices.price_usd", { "$min": "$prices.price_usd" }] }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```